# How visual objects fit in the screen in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

This is my QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  title: qsTr("Hello World")

  GridLayout {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    anchors.margins: 8
    rowSpacing: 5
    columnSpacing: 5
    columns: 4

    Repeater {
      model: 12
      Rectangle {
        width: 100 / Screen.devicePixelRatio
        height: 100 / Screen.devicePixelRatio
        color: 'blue'

        Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: index + 1; color: 'white' }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I set `model` of `Repeater` is `12`, the view is good like this:
[image: Image-1]
But if I set `model` of `Repeater` is `36`+ I get this view:
[image: Image-2]
I want all rectangles to be sized and aligned according to the screen / window size. I want any rectangle doesn't overflow invisible space.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

f you want it to occupy all the vertical space available then you must make a calculation of the height of each rectangle:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
  id: win
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  title: qsTr("Hello World")

  GridLayout {
    id: gl
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    anchors.margins: 8
    rowSpacing: 5
    columnSpacing: 5
    columns: 4

    readonly property real heighItem : {
            var rowCountEffective =  Math.round(repeater.count/gl.columns)
            var heightEffective = win.height-rowCountEffective*gl.rowSpacing - gl.anchors.topMargin -gl.anchors.bottomMargin
            return heightEffective/(rowCountEffective * Screen.devicePixelRatio)
        }

    Repeater {
      id: repeater
      model: 50
      Rectangle {
        width: 100 / Screen.devicePixelRatio
        height: gl.heighItem
        color: 'blue'    
        Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: index+1; color: 'white' }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe do the calculation only once and not in each delegate

Comment: @GrecKo that's true, in a moment I'll update my code. Thanks